# How to Ignore Specific Index When Working With Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe `df` that looks like this:

```
             M            V             O
    2019-07-05   2019-07-05    2019-06-05
BV          10           20            30
CW          40           50            60
```

I want to get to this, (with all the data as integers):

```
M  10
V  20
O  30
```

But when I do:

```
output = df.loc['BV']
print(output)
```

it keeps the 2nd index (the date), like so:

```
M  2019-07-15  10
V  2019-07-09  20
O  2019-06-04  30
Name: BV, dtype: object
```

And rather than integers, the values are still objects.

How can I achieve the desired output/data type?

Comment: Do you want to *drop* that index entirely? Or only have it ignored when you index?

Comment: looks like the dataframe has double-level columns, so `.loc['BV']` returns a double-index series.

Comment: @user3483203. I have no plans to use it so whatever will make my life easier and the code more readable is preferred

Comment: Then use `df.columns = df.columns.get_level_values(0)`, and continue as before.

Comment: @ user3483203 - thanks that worked. If you add as an answer I can mark it as solved

Answer (score 0):

Let us remove the multiple index impact

```
df.T.reset_index(level=1,drop=True).loc[:,'BV']
Out[237]: 
M    10
V    20
O    30
Name: BV, dtype: object
```